# Receiving "Namespace prefix 'bin' has not been declared" error - Saxon's XSL3

Tags: xslt, bit-manipulation, saxon, xslt-3.0

I tried using the bitwise library on Saxon's XSL3 (-PE), but keep receiving the following error message:

```
XPST0081: Namespace prefix 'bin' has not been declared
```

The line that contains the bin code looks like that:

```
<xsl:variable name="firstCharPos" select="bin:shift(bin:hex('000001'), 17)"/>
```

And my stylesheet section looks like that:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    extension-element-prefixes="saxon"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs saxon mf"
    version="3.0">
```

Am I missing something? Should I include the 'bin' library somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to use the EXPath bin module?  I think PE and EE support it.  But of course you need to declare its namespace.

Comment: Yes, that's the module I want to use. How exactly should I declare it on the namespace? Couldn't find proper documentation of it, and just adding 'bin' to the 'exclude-result-prefixes' didn't work...

Comment: The documentation is here: http://expath.org/spec/binary#namespaces

Comment: A namespace declaration looks like `xmlns:bin="http://expath.org/ns/binary"`, like the other namespaces you have declared on the stylesheet element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the namespace declaration

```
 xmlns:bin="http://expath.org/ns/binary"
```

You might also want to add "bin" to the list of prefixes in exclude-result-prefixes (or change it to `exclude-result-prefixes="#all"`).